# How to write/read a file from/to Xcode 6 new directory structure?

Tags: ios, xcode6, directory-structure

I have developed an app which captures an URL and write it locally with some changes to be used later in a Webview. However, after upgrade it to Xcode 6, I have noticed that the directory structure changes every time that it runs. The following commands show me it:

```
    rootUrl = [fm URLForDirectory:NSLibraryDirectory
                         inDomain:NSUserDomainMask
                appropriateForURL:nil
                           create:YES
                            error:&error]
```

The result is something like this:
Root directory: file:///Users/pedrolopes/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1E639C44-89CB-4E1F-8E7A-74AF689F937A/data/Containers/Data/Application/246677E0-B577-4D99-963D-BE3DE3BAAC2A/Library/

I need to store (and delete) files from internet which changes every week and also I need to keep a file that will be inserted into these stored files to be used later.

Is there a way to locate a place to do it into the directory structure of my app?

Thanks,

Pedro.

Answer (score 0):

You can locate it by using

```
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it will only return to me the same result as before. I need a place that doesn't change the location. Or every time that the app runs, the information stored will be lost.

Comment: For that you have to use database like sqlite or core data or store it in NSUserDefault.